# How do I define the type that the useState hook is expecting if I want to store an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to store an array of objects using the `useState` hook but cannot get the syntax for describing the type it is expecting. The type that I would like to store is `Array<Updates>`.

Here is my code:

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<any>([]);
```

#### Update

I have chosen to map through the array of `Updates` and would now like to store each `Update` which is a plain object but am getting the error `Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Update | (() => Update)'.` with this code:

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Update>({}); // object in brackets is underlined with the error.
```

Comment: What about `const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<Updates>([]);` is not working for you? This should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks @AndrejJurkin, do you mean `const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<Updates>>([]);` where you are missing the last angled bracket? When trying that I am getting the error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Updates[]'` but `name` is however defined as a property in `Updates`

Comment: I just missed the second bracket, yes. Isn't that because you're trying to type something like `messages.name` ? Don't forget messages is an array. So objects are accessed by index.  try `messages[0].name`, if it's still an error, then try posting Updates type here.

Comment: Thanks very much, that fixed it! I've now decided to map through the array before storing it and am getting another error - have updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because `{}` is not `Update`. If I understand correctly, you want Update to be nullable.

Something like this should work for you:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Update | null>(null);
```

This means `messages` (which btw you should probably rename to `update` for better readability) could be either null or an `Update` type of object.

This will produce an error if you try to use it without null checks.

Something like `messages.name` will result to an error that messages might be null.

You can fix it either by writing something like `const name = messages && messages.name` or a simple if statement.

```
if (messsages)
 // do something here
 const name = messages.name;
}
```

If you're 100% that messages is never null at the time you're trying to access it you can unwrap it by using `!` like this: `const name = messasges!.name;`

Comment: Great description :)

Answer (score 0):

You are currently defining component state as single Update object, but you need to define it as array of those objects:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Update[]>([]);
```

Later when you need to replace specific item in array you can do it like this:

```
var message = messages[3]; // lets say you want to change name of forth message
Object.assign([], messages, { 3: { ...message, name: 'New Name' } });
setMessages(messages);
```